# How to change Form.Quality property on the runtime (for iOS)

Tags: ios, delphi

I use Berlin to create mobile application for iOS and have some issue. Quality property is set to HighPerfomance on the main form (design time mode is used). This is the code I use:

```
constructor TfmMain.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Quality := TCanvasQuality.HighQuality;
end;
```

The property changes and equals to HighQuality, but control and lines look incorrect. If I change the property in the Object Inspector all seems to work properly, controls and lines look nicely. Could you please advise, what should I do to change Quality on the run time?

#### HighPerformance

[image]

#### HighQuality

[image]

So, after some investigation I override this method:

```
procedure TfmMain.InitializeNewForm;
begin
  Quality := TCanvasQuality.HighQuality;
  inherited; 
end;
```

Now all looks fine. Thanks all.

Comment: Your use of english language is terrible, I don't understand what you're stuck with, try to edit your post please.

Comment: @DamienBannerot It looks good now, and it looks like a great question too.

Comment: @Jerry It's pretty weak without some screenshots

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Added some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

What most likely happens is : Your value is set correctly in the constructor, then the FMX is streamed and the value present in the FMX override the one you set programmatically.

The right place to set a value that is also found in a form's FMX would be in an overridden "Loaded" procedure.

```
procedure TfmMain.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  Quality := TCanvasQuality.HighQuality;
end;
```

That would be my best guess.

Comment: thank you for answer, this approuch with Loaded is incorrect, but you give idea and after investigate I have working code

Comment: sorry for my English :-)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Berlin for iOS dev, but this code :

```
{$IFDEF RELEASE}
Quality := TCanvasQuality.HighQuality;
{$ENDIF}
```

is executed only in release mode, if you're trying to set `HighQuality` for your `Quality` object in debug, try removing the code with brackets.

EDIT :
Answer irrelevant since OP told he understood concept of `$IFDEF` and remove that part from his code.

Comment: thank you, for answer, but I know what this def doing and problem not with this.

Comment: You've reproduced the code in the question, which apparently does not meet requirements.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I "reproduced the code in the question" to point the particular part of the OP code I was talking about, why are you commenting ?

Comment: I'm commenting because you don't appear to have answered the question that was asked. The asker wants to know why the code in the question, reproduced in your answer, doesn't influence the behaviour at runtime.

Comment: And my answer is because he is probably testing in an other mode than release, and the lines I pointed out tell to not execute this while in other mode than release. Seems like a response to me, really don't know why you're downvoting

Comment: The code in the question does not have a conditional. Asker is making the point that setting this property in the constructor has no effect. That's what the question is about.

Comment: Actually {$IFDEF RELEASE} ... {$ENDIF} is a condition, that's what I'm saying in my answer. An I really well understood the question thanks

Comment: The code in the question does not include that conditional though does it? It came from an earlier edit. But the asker removed it, no doubt because he understand hows conditionals work and his test was performed with `RELEASE` defined. I don't think you do understand the question.

Comment: No notification, I didn't see the update. Now you are judging my answer on a different context than when I answered. Still I understand the question, stop believing you're above other people man.

Comment: I don't think I believe that I am above other people. I just think that this answer does not address the question.

Comment: It did. until it didn't.